# Why craco build fails?

Tags: reactjs, craco

I'm building my app with Craco and running `craco build` gives me
this output:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Error: html-webpack-plugin could not minify the generated output.
  In production mode the html minifcation is enabled by default.
  If you are not generating a valid html output please disable it manually.
  You can do so by adding the following setting to your HtmlWebpackPlugin config:
  |
  |    minify: false
  |
  See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options for details.
  For parser dedicated bugs please create an issue here:
  https://danielruf.github.io/html-minifier-terser/
  Parse Error: <<<<<<< HEAD
```

Does this output mean that my index.html is invalid ?

Comment: At a guess you've messed something up in your `craco.config.js` file.

Comment: @Mark, I have the same problem when trying to create an optimized production build for my react app. Did you find any solutions?